# Error 403 Forbidden al quitar la extensión .html de mi url

Tags: html, .htaccess, hosting, error-403

Saludos a la comunidad de Stack Overflow,

Espero que puedan brindarme su apoyo con un inconveniente que surgió durante el desarrollo de un sitio web para la empresa en la que actualmente trabajo.

Previo a la migración, el sitio funcionaba en ColdFusion, pero debido a problemas de rendimiento y funcionalidad, se decidió cambiar la programación. El líder del proyecto canceló el servicio de hosting anterior sin previo aviso, resultando en la pérdida de toda la información. Después de contratar un nuevo servicio de host, surgieron problemas con DNS, errores 404, 403, entre otros.

Actualmente, muchos de los problemas se han solucionado, pero persiste el error 403 Forbidden. Este inconveniente afecta solo a algunas partes del sitio, a pesar de haber otorgado los permisos necesarios y haber contactado al soporte de Hostinger (donde se hospeda el sitio). Se han revisado registros, concedido permisos, desactivado plugins, reiniciado permisos de archivos y directorios, eliminado la caché, escaneado en busca de malware y verificado el A Record. Sin embargo, ninguna de estas soluciones ha funcionado hasta ahora.

Lo único que ha tenido un impacto fue deshabilitar el archivo .htaccess, pero esto mantiene la extensión html en las URL, y se requiere que no la tengan. Mi archivo .htaccess actualmente contiene lo siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^%{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier orientación o solución que puedan proporcionar. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: puedes mostrar el contenido de tu archivo .htaccess o .ini???

Comment: Haz clic en [edit] y agrega el código de tu `.htaccess` en la pregunta. Los comentarios no son adecuados para añadir código, sobre todo si son tan extensos. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour] y a leer [mre].

Comment: Si, muchas gracias por la sugerencia @MauricioContreras

Answer (score -1):

Has intentado quitar las extensiones con el `htaccess` ??

Uno de mis Snippets preferidos

```
# Quitar extensión de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# END Quitar extensión de las URL
```

Eso te permite usar las URL sin las extensiones **.html** y **.php** pero puedes agregar más.

Comment: Ok, muchisimas gracias, si ya intente quitar las extensiones con el htacces, sin embargo es curioso porque he intentado hacerlo con las líneas que me compartes y no las quita, lo que me ha funcionado de momento es lo siguiente:

Comment: Que raro, nunca ha fallado antes. Bueno, intenté ayudarte, sorry 

Comment: Si, agradezco tu comentario @OCHOA, eso es lo extraño, que anteriormente ya había utilizado ese código y funcionó, sin embargo en esta ocasión no me funciono.